# Trying to find out the name of a scifi movie - aliens with speargun-like weapons

Tags: story-identification, aliens, soft-sci-fi

Trying to find out the name of a movie that was late 70's scifi. It had elf like aliens in it that used a weapon that was like a speargun and it was powered by fruit like orb, that resembled a kumquat. Any help at all would be most grateful.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As always, the more info you provide, the luckier you're likely to get. Obviously you've already thought of that, and I'm sure you tried to put down what you remember, but is there anything else? Was it a Hollywood film? Was it indie, was it not from America, most likely? Can you remember anyone who might have been in it? Intended audience? Presumably it was live-action? Any half-remembered plot details? Cover on the VHS box?